# ASP.net render meta tag validly

Tags: c#, asp.net, servercontrols

HTML:

```
<meta name="description" runat="server" id="MetaDescription" content="" />
```

Codebehind:

```
MetaDescription.Attributes["content"] = ThisBlog.MetaDescription;
```

This renders as:

```
<meta id="HeadContent_MetaDescription" name="description" content="My page description"></meta>
```

As per [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10237/redundant-meta-attributes/10238#10238) it needs to have no ID attribute, and close with `/>`.

How can I make it render in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am still on .net 3.5 but put this in Page_Load and it will do what you need:

```
HtmlMeta keywords = new HtmlMeta();
keywords.Name = "keywords";
keywords.Content = "one two trhee;
Header.Controls.Add(keywords);
```

PS: the example is for the keywords tag but the result is the same.

Answer (score 3):

You should remove the `id` property from the `<meta>`, this means the control won't be accessible from the server side by `id` but instead of it it could be dynamically created and then added to the page:

```
HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
meta.Name = "keywords";
meta.Content = ThisBlog.MetaDescription;
this.Header.Controls.Add(meta);
```